# why my exec function is failing in live server?

Tags: php, mp3, exec

I write a exec function to convert ogg to mp3 in my local its working fine but my main server its through an error trans failed.

below is my code.

```
exec("oggdec $file_path/{$file_name}.ogg -o - | lame - $file_path/{$file_name}.mp3",$output,$return);
```

file_path and file_name is also correct.

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is. Are you on a dedicated hosting or shared hosting. Most shared hosting disallow OS functions.

Comment: no my site is dedicated hosting only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean shared host by **live server** :

In most of shared hosts the OS functions are restricted because of security risks.

---

**Update:**
You can also run a command like this, try it for testing if its allowed or not :

```
$cmd = `ls -l`;
echo $cmd;
```

Or:

```
shell_exec('ls -l');
```

Comment: is your server Linux?